# Icon in Gridview Column cell

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i am want to display Image instead of value in gridview column cell. For Eg
GSM Level currently it shows 1,2,3,4,5 level i want to display the same one image icon where it shows network level like we see in mobile network level

Comment: i am sorry but i dont know anything about " same one image icon where it shows network level like we see in mobile network level" .. can you please be more expressive

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

1) Define a function in the code-behind of the page that has the Grid View to return the image path:

```
public string GetImageToDisplay(int level)
{
  string imagePath = string.empty;

  switch(level)
  case 1: imagePath  = "myimagepath/image1.jpg"; break;
  /*other cases*/
  default: break;

  return imagePath;
}
```

2) In the aspx code, put the image column and select the image using the function

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="My Image Column">
<ItemTemplate> 
  <asp:Image ID="MyImage" Runat="Server" 
             ImageUrl='<%# GetImageToDisplay((int)Eval("MyLevelFieldName")) %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```